# Django: How to manage groups and permission without using default admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-permissions

I am working on Django project as per requirements I need to manage users, groups and permissions in custom template. So I am not using default admin dashboard.

I have completed user creation module, now I want to assign permissions and groups to a user.

I have not override or customize any `auth Model` yet. But in future I need to Customize `User Model` e.g some additional fields etc.

First thing that comes in my mind to delete all permissions from `auth_permission` table and add my custom permissions.

So I have to do following things:

1. Create group
2. Permissions List
3. Assign permissions to each group
4. Assign group or permissions to each user

I have some concerns about these things.

- If I have deleted all permissions, will it be OK for project?
- Django functions for validate permissions like has_perm would work?
- Can I do some different thing for it?

Needs some healthy tips.

updated:
I want to show admin only my custom permissions like perm1, perm2. Currently there are others many permissions.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand at all why you want to delete permissions from the auth_permission table, please explain why you're doing this.

Comment: @CrazyCasta I want to show admin only my custom permissions like perm1, perm2. Currently there are others many permissions. I dont want to show all those.

Comment: Oh, you're saying if you use like user.user_permissions that you don't want to see ones that aren't yours. I'd suggest that the best of doing something like that would be to filter that list for only the permissions you're interested in. Based on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions you'll probably run into some trouble if you try to do what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"If I have deleted all permissions, will it be OK for project?"**

If you try to get rid of existing permissions django might just recreate them, or you may run into trouble when creating new models. I'm not sure on the details of when the get created/recreated, but django has [default permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) for every model you create.

**"Django functions for validate permissions like has_perm would work?"**

As long as you create permissions either by [Programmatically creating permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions) or by putting [Custom Permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) in a model's Meta class you should be able to use them like any other permissions. Specifically I mean you should be able to use [user.has_perm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) and the [permission_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) decorator.

**"Can I do some different thing for it?"**

If you want to only show certain permissions from something like user.user_permissions I'd suggest filtering the results you get instead of trying to get rid of existing permissions. Something like the following would be appropriate:

```
filter_show_permissions = ["perm_a", "perm_b", ...]
filtered_permissions = [perm for perm in user.user_permissions
                        if perm in filter_show_permissions]
```